# svg linejoin imlementation differs in different applications

Tags: join, svg, line, vector-graphics

I write an svg parser.

I have an svg file with the following string:

```
<polygon fill="#969696" stroke="#323232" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="555.583,394.805 564.085,394.805 564.02,394.817 568.896,399.655"/>
```

And this picture looks different in various applications. Possible cases:

1)linejoin = bevel

2)linejoin = miter (Corel Draw)

3)two nearest points are not connected (Inkscape, adobe illustrator)

The second and the third case look look like:

[image]

It seems that svg documentation advices to draw the same picture as corel draw draws (right picture). But it is not very pretty.

So what rule will allow to achieve the left picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a bogus co-ordinate in your polygon. The polygon has 3 vertices but you're supplying 4 and the bogus one is confusing things. Try this instead...

```
<polygon fill="#969696" stroke="#323232" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="555.583,394.805 564.085,394.805 568.896,399.655"/>
```